# Changing position of children in <body> tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, children, traversal

I am trying to change to position of children of the body.  I obviously do not understand how to do so, but I thought it would be novel if the following code would work:

```
var temp = $('body').children()[0];
$('body').children()[0] = $('body').children()[1];
$('body').children()[1] = temp;
```

Sadly for me, it does not.  I have searched and found the .add() method, but I do not see how to add to the beginning of a parent/I don't know how to delete another child.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To swap the children just use [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) to stick whichever element you want at the beginning, like this:

```
$('body').children().eq(1).prependTo('body');
```

By swapping elements in the array you're just changing the elements in the jQuery object, references to the object...not really affecting them in the DOM at all.

To [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) an element directly that form looks like this (and is basically what the above gets transformed into):

```
$('body').prepend($('body').children().eq(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

This will change the position of 2 or more items in the body.

Basically, it just reverses the position of elements in the body.

It goes through each child of the `body` and adds that child to the *beginning* of the body. This will reverse the order and thus position of the elements in the body.

```
$('body').children().each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo("body");
});​
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KknEp/)

(**[for 3 elements](http://jsfiddle.net/rSUSm/)**)

**References:**
**[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**
**[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**
**[`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put children element into specified position you can use before,after like this:

`jsFiddl`

**References:**

[each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

api.jquery.com/after/

api.jquery.com/find/

api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Could you please post a reference for the functions you're using?

Comment: Sorry but I dont have enough reputation pts to add them as links thats why references are exposed as plain text